# C++ template class causes infinite loop on destruction

Tags: c++, c++11

So, I have base class and derived class with template
It works fine, until I try to delete derived classes.
I tested making derived class as one piece, or without  template and it worked fine, but when I split it to .h and .cpp files I'm getting errors

This works fine

```
template<class T>
    class NodeTT: public Node
    {
    private:
        T _data;
    public:
        NodeTT(Node* parent = nullptr):Node(parent){}
        NodeTT(T data, Node* parent = nullptr):Node(parent),_data(data){}
        ~NodeTT(){std::cout<<"deriv destr"<<std::endl;}
        void show(){
            std::cout<<_data<<std::endl;
            for(Node* childNode : _children)childNode->show();
        }
    };
```

Same class in two files

```
HEADER
#include <iostream>
#include <node.h>

template<class T>
class TNode: public Node
{
private:
    T _data;
public:
    TNode(Node* parent = nullptr);
    TNode(T data, Node* parent = nullptr);
    ~TNode();
    void show();
};

SOURCE
template<class T>
TNode<T>::TNode(Node *parent) : Node(parent){}

template<class T>
TNode<T>::TNode(T data, Node* parent): Node(parent),_data(data){}

template<class T>
TNode<T>::~TNode(){
    std::cout<<"deriv destr"<<std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void TNode<T>::show(){
    std::cout<<_data<<std::endl;
    for(Node* childNode : _children)childNode->show();
}

template class TNode<int>;
template class TNode<float>;
template class TNode<std::string>;
```

And this destructor of base class

```
Node::~Node(){
    std::cout<<"base destr"<<std::endl;
    for(Node* childNode : _children)
    {
       delete childNode;
    }
    delete _parentNode;
    _children.clear();
}
```

in output i'm getting infinite messages "base destr", so any help with pointing my mistakes will be appreciated

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Your mistake is including random bits of code in your question, which fail to meet the requirements of a [mcve]. It's not possible to take what you posted, compile it, and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not necessarily related to your problem, but consider having a virtual destructor...

Comment: `delete _parentNode;`  -- that looks very suspicious.

Comment: @AlexG - We don't see the base class `Node`. It very well could be. Vasily, do as Sam asked, and post a [mcve].

Comment: It's hard to see how splitting the code into different files caused this. Suppose it could be a strange artefact of all the UB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still haven't provided a **complete** program that compiles, runs, and shows the problem. But `delete _parentNode;` looks wrong. If this is a hierarchy of nodes, the parent node is **already being destroyed** when it calls destructors for the children. Having those children delete that parent node tries to destroy the parent again, which would, in turn, try to destroy all of those children that are already being destroyed. That gives you a nasty loop.

Comment: damn, it really was a problem, How could I not notice this? Now i'm embarrassed xD

Comment: @Vasily -- there's nothing to be embarrassed over. I recognized it because I've spent far too much time debugging recursive destructor calls in my own code.